# Determining shell success asynchronously?

Tags: shell, posix

If a POSIX-compliant shell fails to execute a command it immediately exits with status `127`.

Is it possible to immediately determine that such a shell has succeeded in executing a command *without* waiting for the command (and thus the shell) to exit? (NOT the exit status of the command!) In particular I'm thinking of commands like `xterm` that don't exit until the user chooses to terminate them.

If this can't be done portably can it be done non-portably? Under Linux, or just with Bash or some other subset of shells?

Comment: read the man page for `kill` and check out the part about `kill -0 $PID` near the bottom (in Linux, anyway). If can run your cmd in the background, this might help you. Good luck.

Comment: That looks like it's portable. Thank you.

Comment: In what sense has a command succeeded (or failed) before it exits?

Comment: It hasn't. The shell's call to `execve` has though. Hence "NOT the exit status of the command!" The only downside to the above is dealing with zombie processes, and the only alternative I've been able to find after a few hours of reading man pages involves `ptrace` and is much more complicated.